# Create different content types on same list using 2010 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I'm trying to set up a SharePoint 2010 workflow to accomplish the following:

1. Item is created on custom list using Content Type A. Workflow triggers on creation and updates status from NEW to PENDING.
2. If field in item is checked and status is NEW, workflow should create a new item using Content Type B on the same list. Some but not all of the fields will be copied to the new item.

SharePoint Designer 2013 will not let me publish the workflow. It shows an error icon next to the action that creates the secondary content type. Hovering the mouse over that icon indicates that I cannot create a new item in the same list.

[image]

**Can creation of two different content types be done using a single workflow, or do I have to initiate a second workflow to create the item using Content Type B?**

Comment: Does it have to create a new item or can the current item just be updated to content type b?

Comment: @EricAlexander - Well, they have different fields so I would think the proper way is to create an item of Content Type B (but I could be wrong). They share about 3 fields out of 20 or so (all of which are site columns), the rest are different according to content type.

Comment: just updating it to content b is sufficient unless there is a need to have content type a and b coexist for some reason. Laura Rogers had detailed this back in the 2007 days I seem to recall

Comment: @EricAlexander - they coexist on the same list, yes. But even when I specify Content Type A or don't specify a content type, it still won't let me create a second item in the workflow triggered by the first item. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The client was in a hurry, so I ended up daisy-chaining two workflows together. The first creates item 1, then updates item 1, which in turn triggers workflow 2, that then creates item 2. Kind of a convoluted way to go about it, I think, but that's SharePoint for you.